# How to convert sentence to category?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm working on NLP problem.
The target column contain 5 types of sentences:

```
"Extremely Positive", "Positive", "Neutral", "Negative", "Extremely Negative"
```

I want to convert those sentences to number [5,4,3,2,1].

Is there a build in `keras` or `python` function to do so ?
or I need to convert it by myself using dictionary ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want to use an Encoder from the sklearn library.

LabelEncoder can be used to transform categorical data into integers:

```
    from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
    label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
    x = ['Positive', 'Neutral', 'Positive', 'Negative']
    encoded = label_encoder.fit_transform(x)
    print(encoded)

    array([0, 1, 0, 2])
```

Answer (score 0):

Using pandas you can just create a dictionary of the ratings and the value of the rating. Then just replace them in the dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2],
            'col2': ['Negative', 'Positive', 'Neutral', 'Neutral', 'Positive', 'Extremely Negative', 'Extremely Positive']})

In [4]: df
Out[4]: 
   col1                col2
0     1            Negative
1     2            Positive
2     2             Neutral
3     3             Neutral
4     1            Positive
5     3  Extremely Negative
6     2  Extremely Positive

rating = {"Extremely Positive": 5, "Positive": 4, "Neutral": 3, "Negative": 2, "Extremely Negative": 1}

In [10]: df.replace({"col2": rating}, inplace=True)
Out[10]: 
   col1  col2
0     1     2
1     2     4
2     2     3
3     3     3
4     1     4
5     3     1
6     2     5
```

An even faster approach would be to use `map()`

```
df['col2'] = df['col2'].map(rating)
```